# SVN - how do I commit previous version back into svn?

Tags: svn

I am in version 100
svn co -r92 http://www.projectname.svn/trunk projectname
seems to work but how do I get this v92 version committed?
If I do an svn up I get conflicts
If I do svn commit it won't work

Any idea's I'm lost here

Answer (score 19):

```
svn up -rHEAD           # be sure you're updated with the latest HEAD
svn merge -rHEAD:92 .   # reverse-merge back to revision 92
svn commit              # commit
```

Comment: Does it keep the last commit *(i.e. the one we want to revert)*? Descriptions are confusing — one says it completely undoing changes, the other ones doesn't mention it.

Comment: @Hi-Angel It keeps the full history - you would have all the revisions up to 100, and revision 101 would be the one that brings it back to the same state as revision 92

Answer (score 0):

you need to reverse merge the revisions on an up to date working copy, then commit. i d recommended against doing that withthe command line client, use a graphical client.

Comment: OK I got it done - weird way. I did an svn del on all files in my working dir. Then did a svn co -r92 http://www.projectname.svn/trunk projectname-v92 made an export from projectname-v92 and added it to my project svn add and svn commit and it works %) I'm happy again

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge back your changes
 svn merge -r100:92 file.txt

Comment: can I do svn merge with a whole directory? svn merge -r100:92 webroot/ It's not working? nor is the -rHead solution mentioned earlier